# Devise Password Controller edit method renders nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've been having a lot of trouble getting devise's reset password page to actually render. I've overrided
the edit function and have been trying to force it to render the view but it ends up as an empty string. Any ideas as to how to make it work?

Side note is that I'm using rails in API mode, is there anything I need to configure to get the page to render?

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  def edit
    self.resource = resource_class.new
    set_minimum_password_length
    resource.reset_password_token = params[:reset_password_token]
    render template: 'devise/users/passwords/edit'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

well, еhough strictly speaking, need to add `view`, but if your app is kind of API with endpoints only, it's not a way for sure, so you shouldn't redefine device methods or whatever.

In the case of API mode, you need to implement route on the FE part, and then use the Device's endpoints to reset-password logic.

Btw, this is a common feature and Device's wiki is presented at least 3 solutions to implement this, please check this link:

https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password

I hope it's help

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make it clear but I did generate the views, the issue is that if I don't put the render line in edit function clicking the reset password gives a no content response, and and trying to render the html.erb file gives a blank string

Comment: so, as I understand, `no_content` response it's kind of success response with status 204, so it's mean that: password is edited successfully you just need to implement something on FE to handle it and show kind of message or whatever